# Sourcing a script from another script does not work on Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I had created a Jenkins Job and two shell scripts

```
b.sh
======

sum()
{
    echo "Sum called from b.sh"
}

a.sh
=======

echo "From Script A"
. ./b.sh

sum // Calling function of b.sh
```

When I execute Jenkins Job  'Script a.sh' is getting called and I hope 'sourcing of' b.sh happens

However, Jenkins errors on the function 'sum' as follows

```
a.sh: line xx: sum:  command not found
```

Please suggest any solution to overcome this

I coped 'b.sh' to $WORKSPACE and added 'set -vx' at 'b.sh' and sourcing happens.

The problem is with calling the function "b.sh::sum()' from 'a.sh'.

Comment: Put `set -vx` at the top of `a.sh`, and incorporate the logs this generates into your question. You should have an additional error from `b.sh` not being found, should it indeed fail to have been sourced.

Comment: Please, again, include the *actual logs* showing the content being sourced. If your logs include content you can't provide, make sure the issue still happens when the scripts are cut down to what you can provide and have provided -- which is to say, provide a [mcve].

Comment: If in your *real* scripts the content is sourced into a subshell and then you try to run the command in a parent shell, well, there's our problem -- but if you only test with the bigger, more complicated script and not the minimal version in the question, then that problem is masked from diagnosis.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins runs jobs under a folder called workspace.
You can see its content by executing `ls -l ${WORKSPACE}` in the "execute shell script" build phase, so you can make sure your scripts are there.

You should make sure your scripts are copied to ${WORKSPACE} before trying to run them. Also, you can call the full script path, avoiding to copy them every time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use "execute shell script" in build phase to write your script. These scripts are copied within a temp directory before to be execute. You can read log to see this mechanism. You will see something like `[node_name] $ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins210549930174147290.sh` this is the real script Jenkins execute.

So when you use relative path to source `b.sh`, nothing append because it does not find any script.

Try to use absolute path to source `b.sh`.